NextJS 13+ rewrites to subdomain issues
Im trying to get my /archives to rewrite to archives.localhost for now. Im trying to understand rewrites and I think I have a basic understanding of it. When I go to the main index page archives.localhost:3000/ thee page loads perfectly but for some reason when I try to load archives.localhost:3000/test I get a 404 error, even though the page exists. What am I doing wrong?
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    experimental: {
        missingSuspenseWithCSRBailout: false,
    },
    async rewrites() {
        return {
            beforeFiles: [
                // rewrite projects to the propper path
                {
                    source: `/:path((?!api|auth|_next).)*`,
                    has: [
                        {
                            type: 'host',
                            value: 'archives.localhost/:path*',
                        },
                    ],
                    destination: '/archives/:path*',
                },
                {
                    // fallback
                    source: '/:path*',
                    destination: '/:path*',
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

export default nextConfig;


Could you please try to correct the rewrite rule by replacing async rewrites() in your code.
async rewrites() {
    return {
      afterFiles: [
        // Here we are rewriting requests to archives.localhost:3000 to archives.localhost
        {
          source: '/archives/:path*',
          destination: 'http://archives.localhost/:path*',
        },
        // This is a Fallback for other requests.
        {
          source: '/:path*',
          destination: '/:path*',
        },
      ],
    };
  }

Please let me know if this helps.
